# Multi-dimensional array and timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, google-calendar-api

Here is the code :

```
var array = [];

$('.body-watch-logo').each(function () {

                array[]['evendId'] = $(this).data('event');
                array[]['timestamp'] = $(this).data('timestamp');

                $now = new Date();
                $outStr = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes();

                alert($outStr);

                if(array[]['timestamp'] == $outStr) {

                        alert('Tring Tring Tring');

                        //do something here

                }

                $i++;
        });
```

.body-watch-logo has several events in it with attributes eventId and startTime. So I want to store this information in array. Then compare the startTime which has only Hour and minute with current-time. If they are equal give an alert. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Use Ajax may be. Please suggest.

Comment: If your timestamps are being recorded somewhere, you should consider using _UTC_, this way you don't have to worry about timezone.

Comment: Hey do you know why am I getting two different times for UTC...

Date {Sat Jun 15 2013 01:32:06 GMT+0200}

2013-06-14T18:30:00.000+02:00

The first one comes from google calendar which also has berlin set... and the second one from my laptop.. which is the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incremented `i`, but never initialized it or used it as your array index. But you don't need to do either, since `.each()` passes the index as an argument to the iteration function. See

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

The elements of the array are better implemented as objects, not sub-arrays.

```
var array = [];

$('.body-watch-logo').each(function (i) {
    array[i] = { event: $(this).data('event'),
                 timestamp: $(this).data('timestamp')
               };

    $now = new Date();
    $outStr = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes();

    alert($outStr);

    if(array[i].timestamp == $outStr) {
            alert('Tring Tring Tring');
            //do something here
    }
});
```

Comment: Link to API docs for `$.each` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ . You can also put a `;` on the end of that _Object_.